# Moving from one SkyTeam partner to another

Tags: loyalty-programs, delta-air-lines, air-france, skyteam

I currently have Silver Medallion on Delta for 2018. However Delta has this stupid MQD thing which make it hard for me to move from silver to gold, plus Delta Skymiles are not very valuable now so am considering shifting to Flying Blue. But I have no points on Flying Blue.

How should I make this transition while also reap benefits of Silver Medallion (or SkyTeam Elite) for 2018?

Answer (score 1):

Your silver medallion status is good for a year.  You can use it even if you are directing points to Flying Blue.  If you think you will qualify again for 2018, then continue saving pounts with Delta so you have enough for 2018 status.  Then start directing points to Flying Blue in January.

Do you have a Delta AMEX?  Depending on which card if you charge a certain amount, Delta waives the MQD requirement.

Comment: In 2018, when I make a booking I will add my Flying Blue to it. But my status is on Delta. So how will I get my benefits in 2018, from Delta, if my Flying Blue is added to my reservation?
I will qualify for 2018. And no I do not have a delta credit card

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way. Airlines within an alliance don't steal members from each other. So they don't offer transfer at the same level. I tried it from KE to AF, and was told it wasn't possible.

I've seen this with airlines of two different alliances: for a while SQ offered the same membership to CX members. I took advantage of it back then, and had a Gold card for a year.

Flying Blue is a generous FF program, especially to people based outside France, but you'll have to start back at Ivory.

Comment: I know I will need to start at Ivory. But my question is if it is possible to start at Ivory but use the benefits of Delta Silver (free bag, priority boarding etc..) but get points for Flying Blue to qualify for 2019

Comment: Nope. If you start at Ivory you get Ivory privileges, not Silver. If you fly Delta with an Ivory Flying Blue card, you won't get Delta Silver privileges.